# Neural Network returns 0.5 instead of 0

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I just followed a [tutorial](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) for a simple neural network. It really helped me to understand the concept. But if I test it with just zeros, so [0,0,0], it returns 0.5 instead of ~0. Why does it do that? What has to be changed for it, to return ~0?

```
X = np.array([ [0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1] ])
y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1
for j in xrange(60000):
    l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
    l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(l1,syn1))))
    l2_delta = (y - l2)*(l2*(1-l2))
    l1_delta = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T) * (l1 * (1-l1))
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += X.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

Thank you and regards

Answer (score 0):

The [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) has a value of `0.5` at the origin. If you want your transfer function to be `0` at the origin, use [`tanh`](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tanh/introductions/Tanh/ShowAll.html) (you'd have to modify your derivative, though).

Comment: But then my neural network would return -1 for false and 1 for true, wouldn't it? So I'd still get a wrong result.
Is my way of thinking wrong, or would a multi layer network fix the problem, since [0,0,0] doesn't change anything with both functions.

Comment: For XOR you usually have to interpret the results in a certa in way. For example, with the logistic function you interpret values `> 0.5` as `1` and values `<= 0.5` as `0`. The logistic and the `tanh` functions are asymptotic and would never give you `1`. You could argue that with the limited precision of `double` the function would eventually produce an effective `0` or `1`, but this is a bit hackish.

Comment: So the script is working properly? Since everthing <= 0.5 means 0, [0,0,0] was correct. I was just confused because other results were 0.0123 or 0.998 for example.

Comment: This is just one way of interpreting it. It kind of depends on you, and admittedly this can be confusing. You could also say that anything `> 0.99` is `1` and anything `< 0.01` is `0`, which seems to be what they have done in the tutorial you link to. They train the network until the output is
[[ 0.00966449]
 [ 0.00786506]
 [ 0.99358898]
 [ 0.99211957]]

Comment: Excactly. But this way the 0.5 doesn't make any sense. I thought there is a way to make it a clear ~0 or ~1. Thank you for the help, tho!

Comment: No worries, I know it can be confusing. For this particular problem, you could scale and shift your sigmoid function, for example, use `1.1 * sigmoid - 0.05`. This way it would be able to give you a clear 1.0 and 0.0.

Comment: Just don't forget to multiply your derivatives by `1.1`. :)